# Can we create a conversation loop in Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Consider a small task where we ask the user to add fruits to the basket one by one in a loop

I have created a small `agent` for this task with the following `intents`

- **Intent**: `basket`
- **Intent**: `basket-yes` *(follow up)*
- **Intent**: `basket-no` *(follow up)*

In the intent `basket` user have to provide a fruit name and quantity. Then

- If the user says "no" then `basket-no` (follow up) intent is triggered and the cart is finished
- If the user says "yes" then `basket-yes` (follow up) intent is triggered which should trigger `basket` intent to allow the user to add more fruits

I have set the input/output context for intents as per the above requirement but the conversation is not moving towards `basket` intent. I don't know if it's the correct way to do it or even if it's possible to do it with Dialogflow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that the Input and Output Contexts don't indicate which Intents *will* be triggered, they indicate which Intents *can* be triggered. Intents are only triggered based on *what the user says or does*. So you never "trigger" an Intent by changing the Context - you can just evaluate which Intents may be valid at any time.

Intents can only be triggered if **all** of their Input Contexts are currently valid *and* the user says something that matches a training phrase. So your "basket" Intent will only be triggered if the `basket-repeat` Context is currently valid and the user says one of the phrases (which you did not show in your screen shots).

Intents are not like state machines, although the Contexts sometimes help you model them that way.

You can do "loops", of a sort, although the user is ultimately in control of how you advance through those loops. While you can't loop through Intents, you can loop through Contexts or state, which influence which Intents may be acceptable at a given moment. And your prompts should certainly reflect the looping nature of what you expect from the user.

I think what is happening is that the `basket-repeat` Context is never set in the first place, so the `basket` Intent can never be matched.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation my doubt is cleared